# qsub slow on cluster with a single computer

Tags: qsub, torque

Torque is installed in a single computer, which is used for both head node 
and computation node. I didnt installed Maui for job schedule, but use the built-in function of torque.

I find qsub is slow when submitting many jobs, for example:

```
for i in `ls *tt.sh`                                                          
do                                                                              
        echo  $i                                                                    
        qsub  $i                                                                    
done
```

it take a while to submit jobs in the end of the scripts list.
This happens even if the computer is in low load. The submission 
is slow if there are merely 70 scripts in the list.

Are there some options I could tweak with torque, or I have to install Maui 
for job scheduling?

Thanks!